# Define Style of DataGridTextColumn tooltip

Tags: wpf, tooltip, wpf-controls

I am trying to change the style of the tooltip of DataGridTextColumn, But the xaml code below doesn't work. When I run the application, custom tooltip is shown and System.Windows.Style is written in it. The button isn't shown too. Where do I have mistake?

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*" Binding="{Binding W_NAME}" Header="Name">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="mytext"/>
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                                                <Border Name="RootElement" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0">
                                                    <Border.Background>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BorderBrush" Color="Black"/>
                                                    </Border.Background>
                                                    <Grid Margin="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                                                          TextElement.FontFamily="{DynamicResource Glaho}"
                                                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                                          Margin="4,5,4,4">

                                                        </ContentPresenter>
                                                        <Button Content="This is button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding somecommand}"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, the problem is you've set the `Style` as the ToolTip itself:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ToolTip"> <-------------- badness!
```

What you need to do is set a ToolTip control as the ToolTip, and then set the Style on that:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ToolTip>
                <ToolTip.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
```